# Radical expression for roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots-of-unity

Can somebody point out a reference to the nested radical formula of the complex roots of unity when $n = 2^N$, i.e. in solving
$x^n=1$ ?

Comment: Are you asking for just a reference to the answer, or do you want the recursion formula for finding the real and imaginary parts of $x$ where $x^{2n}=1$ given the parts for $y$ in $y^n=1$?

Comment: I have computed a recursion formula in nested radicals of 2 starting from angle bisection in the complex plane. But i am sure that somebdy did this before so I was looking for a formula for the root with the minimal arg.

Answer (score 0):

Many books on complex analysis contains such equation. In fact, let $x=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Then$1=x^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, in this case we have $ \cos \frac{ 2 \pi} { n} + i \sin \frac{ 2 \pi}{n}$ but i was asking for a nested radical expression.